# printing upper and lower bytes from int number in C

Tags: c, byte, union

I have to print upper and lower word from int number. I must use union. For example number -1 must be printed as 65535 65535 ; number 255 must be 255 0

What's wrong with my code. Which type will be good for representing word. Can somebody explain my how is it working? Is word a byte or something else?

If I put -1 it print 255 255

```
#include <stdio.h>

union word_set
{
    int x;
    unsigned char tab[4];
};

int main()
{
    union word_set word_set;

    word_set.x=-1
    printf("%d %d", *(word_set.tab), *((word_set.tab) + 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225717/discussion-on-question-by-rescrove-printing-upper-and-lower-bytes-from-int-numbe).

Answer (score 1):

Concluding from your expected output, you will have to use the type `uint16_t` instead of `unsigned char`. Like this:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

union word_set
{
    int x;
    uint16_t tab[2];
};
```

And to format these values as "unsigned", please use "%u".

*Note: The term "word" commonly stems from x86 assembly, where a WORD is a 16-bit value. The DWORD (meaning "double word") is then a 32-bit value. And this restricted view of value types sneaks into all kind of x86 programming.*

Comment: But it is still printing -1 as 255 255, not as 65535 65535

Comment: Please make sure that you changed the right source file, that you saved it, and that you compiled and linked the right files. -- BTW, the source you show in the question is not your real source, because it has compile errors.

Comment: No, C does not allow access outside the array and there is no reason why you wouldn't use tab[2] .

Answer (score 0):

> If I put -1 it print 255 255

`-1` in 32 bit 2'complement gives the binary `0xFFFFFFFF`. No matter which byte you read from the value `0xFFFFFFFF`, you will get `0xFF` = `255`. Your program behaves as expected.

Comment: but I must have 65535 65535

Comment: i must print upper and lower word from int number

Comment: @ResCrove Given `unsigned char tab`, there's no way an 8-bit `char` value will hold values up to 65535....

Comment: so what i have to do?

Comment: @AndrewHenle uint16_t didn't help

Comment: @ResCrove In that case simply `word_set.tab[0] + word_set.tab[1]*256`, assuming little endian.